# Ansible Python interpreter - Module not found Error

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, importerror

I have a main.yml file written for an Ansible playbook where I am calling a python script . My ansible version is 2.9 and the default python script version is 3.6.8 .. I have imported some modules like NetmikoAuthentication and NetmikoTimeout and SSH one but it is acceptable only when I should have a python version >=3.8 and < 4.0 … I have also upgraded my python to 3.8.9 which is shown in my /usr/local/bin/python3.8 … for my python script , I want to specifically call it using 3.8 but it is by far accepting the default python version 3.6 . How to resolve this issue ?? Can anyone help me out . I have even used vars section where I have used
ansible_python_interpreter: “/usr/local/bin/python3.8 “ as my path as well . Still it is not accepting . Any responses will be highly appreciated .

I have tried using vars and I have added

- vars:
  ansible_python_interpreter: “/usr/local/bin/python3.8”

But it is still reflecting the default python version 3.6 only … I am expecting that this python script what I am using should reflect for version 3.8 and not for 3.6 .

Comment: [edit] your question and provide [mre].

Comment: Open the question at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). It's about [tools used for administering, ..., or automating](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Ansible 2.9 has been outdated for 2 years now, you should consider **upgrading**.

Comment: Reproducible example would be needed for your question. This includes minimun code + data

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/python_3_support.html), you should set the python interpreter on the hosts level.

So, on the `hosts` file:

```
[myhosts]
host_1
host_2
...
host_n

[myhosts:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/path/to/python3.8
```

You could also set the default python interpreter on the `ansible.cfg` file.

Comment: I did that , but it did not give me the output , still it shows that the module is not found even after defining ansible_python_interpreter=/path/to/python3.8 … can we create any virtual environment for executing this python version 3.8 ?? If yes , can anyone write down the steps

Comment: Can you show the error output?